# How to set text strikethrough to all element with the same class after onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<button onclick="hello()">Click Me</button>
<p class="myelement">Hello world 1</p>
<p class="myelement">Hello world 2</p>
```

And this is my JS:

```
function hello(){
    alert('hello!');
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("myelement");
    ele.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
}
```

How do I change the text to be strikethrough after I pressed the button?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqa7xjmf/)

Note: I'm looking for vanilla JS approach. Not jQuery way.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jqa7xjmf/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. You need to use `for` loop it iterate the elements returned by it.

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("myelement");
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
    ele[i].style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
}
```

[*DEMO*](https://jsfiddle.net/jsonLtgq/)

Comment: Of the two equivalent answers, this one reads better so up voting it.

Answer (score 6):

Working JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jqa7xjmf/2/

```
for (var i in ele)
    ele[i].style.textDecoration='line-through'
```

ele is an array, so you should change each element by itself

```js
function hello(){
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("myelement");
    for (var i in ele)
 ele[i].style.textDecoration='line-through'
    
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Click Me</button>
<p class="myelement">Hello world 1</p>
<p class="myelement">Hello world 2</p>
```

Comment: This looks equivalent to Satpal's answer, but lacks the explanation they give.  Also, the big blue buttons on this answer don't seem to do anything whereas Satpal's demo works.

Comment: It works, but then I edited it and remove the HTML by mistake. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
    function hello() {
         // Get elements with class 'myclass'.
         var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");

         // Add the strikethrough to all those elements.
         for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 
             ele[i].style.textDecoration = "line-through";
         }    
     }
</script>

<button onclick="hello()">Click Me</button>
<p class="myclass">Hello world 1</p>
<p class="myclass">Hello world 2</p>
```